# Deserializing complex JSON contain array of inherited object types

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have create a class called `RESTObjectBase`. This class is inherited by any number of other classes that include information like persons, address, phone numbers.

I create an `List<RestObjectBase>` containing one or more objects of this type and pass it back to the front end via a REST call.

The JSON that is return is as follows:

```
{
   "Items":[
      {
         "__type":"AnyObjectInheritedFromBaseClass",
         "ObjectType":3,
         "First_Name":"",
         "Last_Name":"",
      }
   ],
   "Status":0
}
```

I am trying to deserialize this at the other end. I've had multiple errors including 'type cannot be null' but that's not really my issue.

Is there any way to deserialize an object of this complexity to the original class/list. Why I'm struggling is it's an array of objects that ultimately inherit `RESTObjectBase` and it doesn't look like the deserializing is smart enough to do this.

The front end deserializing this could be any device or platform so I cannot simply use something like JSON.NET as it's not supported everywhere.

I would even be happy to deconstruct the JSON and serialize each item in the array separately but I cannot figure out how to do this either. I could use the type to work out how to deserialize it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What serializer are you using?  The presence of the "__type" parameter suggests it's either `DataContractJsonSerializer` or `JavaScriptSerializer`.

Comment: Check out the "Paste JSON as Classes" feature in VS. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/18/paste-json-as-classes-in-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-rc.aspx

Comment: Thanks. Both these got me back on the correct path. That and 2 hours sleep :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is all about using the correct serializer. I was serializing with DataContractJsonSerializer so did the same with the deserialize and it worked as expected.

```
        RESTResponse rr2 = null;

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var writer = new StreamWriter(ms);
            writer.Write(textBox1.Text);
            writer.Flush();
            ms.Position = 0;

            DataContractJsonSerializer s = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RESTResponse));

            rr2 = (RESTResponse)s.ReadObject(ms);
        }
```

Although I plan I doing this on many different platforms on mobile devices, I am planning on using Xamarin so I should be able to do the same code.

This also means I could us JSON.NET.